# Vue 3 prop not being passed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, prop, vue-props

I'm trying to pass a simple prop to another component in Vue 3.0.11, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's my App component:

```
<template>
  <Loading :message="Importing"></Loading>
</template>

<script>
import Loading from "./components/Loading.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Loading },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

And my `Loading` component:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ loadingText }}...</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Loading",
  props: ["message"],
  data() {
    return {
      loadingText: this.message || "Loading",
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I'm trying to pass the prop `message` with the value `Importing`, but in the Loading component it's telling me the `message` prop is undefined. Here's a REPREX: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-raman-pweb4

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to pass it into the prop using the `v-bind:` shorthand syntax: `:`.

Vue is expecting you to pass in the variable `Importing`. This doesn't exist, so it resolves as undefined.

Because your message is just an inline string, you need to either remote the `:` or wrap "Importing" with single quotes or backticks (useful if you want to do string interpolations that aren't complex enough to warrant a computed):

```
<Loading message="Importing"></Loading>
```

or

```
<Loading :message="'Importing'"></Loading>
```

This would also work:

```
<template>
  <Loading :message="message"></Loading>
</template>

<script>
import Loading from "./components/Loading.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Loading },
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Importing',
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer as well as clarifying why what I was doing was wrong!

Comment: No worries, @Chris. Happy to have helped. Best of luck!

Comment: Just as a quick side note too. You can use self closing tags in Vue to keep things cleaner. This is recommended by the official style guide. So `<Loading message="Importing" />` instead of `<Loading message="Importing"></Loading>` to keep things cleaner